# Python: Test for equality of certain index in nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the following nested list:

```
nlist = [[2, 0, 4], [2, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4]]
```

I would like to evaluate whether the first element of each list is equal. I have found methods to evaluate whether the entire nested lists are equal, but not specific indexes?

Comment: 'equal' to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) as its parameter.

```
all(sublist[0] == nlist[0][0] for sublist in nlist)
```

In short, `all()` will return `True` if every `sublist[0] == nlist[0][0]` for every sublist in the original list. It will return `False` if any item is not equal to `nlist[0][0]`.

Comment: I was not familiar with the all() function. This works perfectly. Will accept in ten minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a set of the first elements of each sub list, and since there is no repetition in sets, you can see if the length of the set is one:

```
nlist = [[2, 0, 4], [2, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4]]

result = len(set(l[0] for l in nlist)) == 1
print(result) # => False
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the unique first element and then check index :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> nlist = [[2, 0, 4], [2, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4]]
>>> c= [i for i,k in groupby([n[0] for n in nlist])]
>>> c
[2, 0]
>>> d=[[i for i, x in enumerate(nlist) if x[0]==j] for j in c]
>>> d
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> R=dict(zip(c, d))
>>> R
{0: [2, 3], 2: [0, 1]}
```

you get a `dict` with each first possible value and a list of index from your initial list.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_num = nlist[0][0]
for sublist in nlist:
    if first_num != sublist[0]
        print(False)
print(True)
```